# string concatenate question in C++

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I want to concatenate a fileName including path and file names. Then I can open and write it. But I failed to do so.

```
char * pPath;
pPath = getenv ("MyAPP");
if (pPath!=NULL)
//printf ("The current path is: %s",pPath); // pPath = D:/temp

string str = "test.txt";
char *buf = new char[strlen(str)];
strcpy(buf,str);

fullName = ??  // how can I get D:/temp/test.txt 

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(fullName);
outfile << "hello world" << std::endl;

outfile.close();
```

Comment: What on earth are you using a `char` buffer and `strcpy` for?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string str = "test.txt";
char *buf = new char[strlen(str)];
strcpy(buf,str);
```

Should rather be

```
string str = "test.txt";
char *buf = new char[str.size() + 1];
strcpy(buf,str.c_str());
```

But after all, you don't even need that. A `std::string` supports concatenation by `operator+=` and construction from a `char*` and exposes a `c_str` function that returns a c-style string:

```
string str(pPath); // construction from char*
str += "test.txt"; // concatenation with +=

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(str.c_str());
```

Comment: Actually it should be `new char[str.size() + 1]` -- don't forget the null byte at the end.

Comment: @Ernest: I don't know what you mean... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char* const my_app = getenv("MyAPP");
    if (!my_app) {
        cerr << "Error message" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    string path(my_app);
    path += "/test.txt";
    ofstream out(path.c_str());
    if (!out) {
        cerr << "Error message" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    out << "hello world";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char * pPath;
pPath = getenv ("MyAPP");
string spPath;
if (pPath == NULL)
  spPath = "/tmp";
else
  spPath = pPath;

string str = "test.txt";

string fullName = spPath + "/" +  str;
cout << fullName << endl;

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(fullName.c_str());
outfile << "hello world" << std::endl;

outfile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string fullName = string(pPath) + "/" + ...

string fullName(pPath);
fullName += "/";
fullName += ...;
```